# Ejb jndi binding in java code

Tags: binding, ejb, jndi, local, jboss-eap-6

The method is loading  a bean

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Object lookupResult = ctx.lookup("abilitecConsumerClient/local");
```

And another class

```
@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding="abilitecConsumerClient/local" )
@Local()
```

What exactly does represent `abilitecConsumerClient/local`? Is that the path in my local machine that I need to look for this property file or the file I need it loads for this EJB JNDI binding name?

If you can also give info how to specify a custom EJB JNDI binding name in JBoss EAP 6?

This app is going to run on JBOSS EAP 6.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **old** [JBoss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/JNDI_Bindings.html):

> ...when the application is deployed in a *.jar*, session beans will bind to JNDI in the form (...) *ejbName/local* in the case of local interfaces. When the EJBs are deployed in an *.ear* file, the default JNDI binding will be prepended by the name of the *.ear* file.

So, if we have an EAR file which name is *foo.ear* the default JNDI name would be *foo/EJB-NAME/local*.

This behavior can be overriden by defining our own `@LocalBinding` annotation on our bean.

By [definition](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/embedded/api/org/jboss/annotation/ejb/LocalBinding.html), the `@LocalBinding` annotation specifies *the local JNDI binding for an EJB local interface*.

Which means that the value of the element `jndiBinding`, passed on `@LocalBinding`, represents the name associated (binded) to the bean, where the annotation was placed, on the [Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/overview/index.html).

This then allows us to retrieve an instance of the bean, as you mentioned, by looking it up on the JNDI, using the `jndiBinding` defined on the `@LocalBinding` annotation:

```
MyBean bean = ctx.lookup("abilitecConsumerClient/local");
```

**NOW**, regarding your last question, notice that in beginning of my answer I said *...**old** JBoss documentation...*. Why? Because since JBoss EAP 6 ([or JBoss AS 7](http://planet.jboss.org/post/jboss_eap_and_wildfly_a_symbiotic_relationship)), the binding of EJBs to custom JNDI names isn't allowed anymore either by [annotations](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/176194?tstart=0) or [XML configuration](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/177380?tstart=0).

One may assume that it was due to the efforts of Java EE 6 to standardize EJB Namespaces.

You can take a closer look at the [JNDI changes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html-single/Migration_Guide/index.html#sect-JNDI_Changes) present on JBoss EAP 6, where *EJB 3.1 introduced a standardized global JNDI namespace and a series of related namespaces that map to the various scopes of a Java EE application.*

Making a parallel between prior EAP 6 and after, we have:

*Prior to EAP 6*

```
// Bean definition
@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding="custom/MyBean")
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean {
    (...)
}

// look-up
ctx = new InitialContext();
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) ctx.lookup("custom/MyBean");
```

*After EAP 6*

```
// Bean definition
@Stateless
@Local(MyBean.class)
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean {
    (...)
}

// look-up
MyBean myBean = (MyBean)
     InitialContext.lookup("java:module/MyBean");

// or through injection
@EJB
MyBean myBean;
```

Finally, you can find more examples on how to do the EJB look-up on the [JBoss AS 7 examples](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Order+Application+Migration+from+EAP5.1+to+AS7) and take a careful look at the following:

- [Portable JNDI sintax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#girgn)
- [Application-specified Portable JNDI Names](https://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_specified_portable_jndi_names)
- Section "Examples of JNDI mappings in previous releases and how they might look now" of [How do I migrate my application from AS5 or AS6 to AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7)

Comment: Thank you ! @aribeiro , this is very useful info to me.

Comment: another Q's of me. I have also below structure below but not sure what this path CWrapper/env/CClient/webservice stands for ? Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
   Service service = (Service) initialContext.lookup("CWrapper/env/CClient/webservice"); Would u please tell me ur thoughts/info ? ty @aribeiro

Comment: @docaUS, it is similar to the question you previously made: that "path" is the JNDI resource name associated to the bean *Service*. But again, since JBoss EAP 6, the binding of EJBs to custom JNDI names isn't allowed anymore. How's the *Service* class defined?

Comment: it is an interface class of javax.xml.rpc.Service . it is calling from there

Comment: So, doing `(Service) initialContext.lookup("CWrapper/env/CClient/webservice");` you're simply attaining a reference for the JAX-RPC web service factory.